# How to Receive and download text document from a user in Telegram in C# using the WTelegramClient library?

Tags: c#, telegram, wtelegramclient

I have a C# Windows Form program that uses the WTelegramClient library to connect to the telegram API. I need the program to download a text document that has been sent to me by another telegram user (not a bot or channel). To get all the messages between me and the user I have applied this code:

```
Messages_MessagesBase history = await this.client.Messages_GetHistory(peer);
```

the "history" variable has an array "Messages" which contains all the messages and "peer" is the InputPeer for the other user.I tried using this code :

```
await client.DownloadFileAsync();
```

but this method needs two parameters the first one is : (Document document) and the second is (Stream outputStream). How can get these two parameters?

Comment: When tagging remember: ***`C` != `C#`***

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [this](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/Examples/Program_DownloadSavedMedia.cs) example

basically you need to find the document inside `message.media` and pass it to the method, and the second parameter can be a `FileStream` or any type of stream you want